# Посоветуйте бесплатный хостинг

Tags: python, хостинг

Я создал дискорд бота, и чтобы мой компьютер не работал 24/7 я решил закинуть свой код на  хостинг replit. Всё бы ничего, но только как я закрываю браузер, бот почти сразу останавливается. Посоветуйте нормальный бесплатный хостинг с поддержкой Python

Comment: За бесплатно, ваш бот будет падать столько раз, сколько это будет нужно тому провайдеру где вы зарегаетесь. Вот вообще не проблема найти сейчас VPS за 200-300р в месяц и пусть он там крутится пока не устанет. (ну объективно же 2 пачки не дорогих сигарет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать [Heroku](https://heroku.com), он поддерживает не только Python, но у него есть минус из бесплатных БД у него только PostgreSQL и там совсем небольшой объем. Деплой на нём производится, либо с помощью GitHub, либо с их собственного модуля Git. Также на heroku, если у приложения нет активности 30 минут, оно "засыпает", но не выключается. Если для вас это критично можете использовать [этот сервис](https://kaffeine.herokuapp.com/).

*(И если вы из России, то регистрироваться на хероку придётся через прокси)*.

Либо же [PythonAnywhere](https://pythonanywhere.com), он поддерживает и MySQL и PostgreSQL, и с ним меньше мороки с деплоем. Но есть ограничение на количество процессорных секунд.